# node_save causing duplicates

Tags: 7, nodes

I've seen a few other issues where people were causing this by calling node_submit followed by node_save, but I'm not - any ideas why this is creating a duplicate of every piece of content?

```
$art = node_load($node->nid);
$field_language = field_language('node', $art, 'field_intro');
$art->field['field_intro'][$field_language][0]['value'] = $record->intro;
node_submit($art);
print $art->title . ' saved <br />';
```

I've tried both node_save and node_submit, both with the same results

EDIT: sorry guys, it was a conflict with a bit of code from another custom module - nothing to see here!

Comment: If there is variable `$node`, then you should not use `node_load` function again to load same node. Please share your complete code.

Comment: The $node variable wasn't actually the Drupal $node variable, bad naming on my part which I have changed now.

Comment: If there is "nothing to see here", you might want to consider deletion before it will get closed. Or revert it back to the state that was a real question, and post a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the content of existing entity than you may use [field_attach_update($entity_type, $entity)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7): this saves field data for an existing entity.

Example:

```
$art = node_load($node->nid);
$field_language = field_language('node', $art, 'field_intro');
$art->field_intro[$field_language][0]['value'] = $record->intro;
field_attach_presave('node', $art);
field_attach_update('node', $art);
```

**Note:** `field_attach_update()` always expects all fields (like we are [passing the complete node object as `$art`), but If you just pass it the fields you actually want to update it will drop others like image or file fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [node_save() documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7):

> If $node->nid is omitted (or $node->is_new is TRUE), a new node will be added.

So, check the loaded node to make sure there's an `->nid` set on it, and `->is_new` is not set to `TRUE`. And I'd definitely use `node_save()` here.

Additionally, the syntax for changing an existing field should be: `$art->field_intro[$field_language][0]['value']`. And, if your fields always use the same language as the node, you can just use `$node->language` instead of loading the field language implicitly.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If I'm loading the node with node_load, how can the nid be omitted? I've tried swapping the variable names so it uses $node instead, but still creating duplicates.

Comment: It shouldn't be, which is why it's strange that your code example wouldn't work (except for the setting of the field value, it's what I normally do when I just need to update a field value).